# how to correct improper results of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an interesting problem that isn't returning the expected results.

I am pulling a list of 50 names from a database and placing those into an array, which works just fine. Then I need to be able to add a first initial of the last name to the array. When attempting to do so, the final resulting array only ends up with the {NAME} z, and not the expected results. Here's my present code

```
$init_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');

foreach($names as $id=>$name){

    foreach($init_array as $ks=>$vs){
        $names[$id] = $name . ' ' . $vs . '<br>';
    }
}




foreach($names as $id=>$name){

    echo $name . '<br>';
}
```

My results now show something like:

```
Arnetta z

Arnette z

Arnita z

Arnold z

Arnoldo z
```

When in fact it should show:

```
Arnetta a

Arnetta b

Arnetta c
```

And so on. So my question is this - does the array have a limit to the amount of data it can store? I have in fact set a memory limit of:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

And the code appears to be right to add the intended first initial of a last name the to the name array. Am I incorrect with how the code is developed? What's the proper way to adjust the code for the intended results?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are just overwriting the value in your names array again and again. Sounds like you want to concatenate the name instead of overwriting it.

Comment: So in the end, you want each name in `$names` to have a variant for each letter in the array?  (side hint - shorten that big ugly letter array [with `range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php), as in `$init_array = range('a','z');` )

Comment: So, you want 26 * [# number of `$names`]  lines in the result?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the values to the same index of array so it contains the last value of the array try multidimentional array like this

```
$init_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z');

foreach($names as $id=>$name){

    foreach($init_array as $ks=>$vs){
        $names[$id][] = $name . ' ' . $vs . '<br>';
    }
}



print_r($names);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$count=0;

foreach($names as $id=>$name){

    $names[$id] = $name . ' ' . $init_aray[$count]. '<br>';
    $count++;

}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with counting the array, and doesn't come close to solving the issue at hand.